# Bower Installing a large amount of dependencies

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ubuntu, bower

running `bower install` in my terminal seems to be downloading a surprisingly large number/amount of dependencies. The below progress log for installing jquery through `bower install jquery --save` shows that 11+ MB of data has been downloaded. The installation finally endedat 14+ MB. I've seen other people use bower to install jquery and it takes nowhere near as long as it takes me and nowhere near as much data to download a small package like jquery. How can this issue be resolved?

```
  bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.09 MiB | 33 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.11 MiB | 116 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.14 MiB | 30 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.17 MiB | 29 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.21 MiB | 32 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.25 MiB | 33 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.28 MiB | 32 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.32 MiB | 35 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.37 MiB | 39 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.40 MiB | 41 KiB/s
bower progress      jquery#* Receiving objects:  90% (4371/4819), 11.48 MiB | 44 KiB/s
```

UPDATE
Issue is not only with `jquery`. Below is an `angular` install at 37% complete and close to 20MB. The install finished at an awe inspiring 187MB!

```
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8695/22905), 18.03 MiB | 31 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8697/22905), 18.04 MiB | 30 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8697/22905), 18.08 MiB | 30 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8699/22905), 18.10 MiB | 31 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8699/22905), 18.14 MiB | 29 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8699/22905), 18.18 MiB | 29 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8700/22905), 18.21 MiB | 31 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8700/22905), 18.23 MiB | 33 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8701/22905), 18.28 MiB | 34 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8701/22905), 18.32 MiB | 35 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8702/22905), 18.36 MiB | 37 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8703/22905), 18.39 MiB | 38 KiB/s
bower angular#>= 1.2.0                                progress Receiving objects:  37% (8703/22905), 18.42 MiB | 35 KiB/s
```

My bower.json is as below

```
 {
      "name": "testing bower",
      "authors": [
        "XXXXXu XXXz Mxxxxxxda <xxxxxxxa@gmail.com>"
      ],
      "description": "ask the name",
      "main": "index.html",
      "license": "MIT",
      "homepage": "",
      "private": true,
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.0.0",
        "grunt": "^1.0.1",
        "angular-gridster": "^0.13.10"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does your `bower.json` file look like?

Comment: I just edited with the `bower.json`